# Receiver package not found, unregister application

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I am newer to Android and trying to implement some applications using Google Cloud Messaging.  I originally had set up a single application, and have now split my application into two (a server and a client).

My GCM intents were working, but when I split my application, I divided packages up.  My old application was `<base.package>` and now the two are `<base.package>.client` and `<base.package>.server`.

Now, on my client application (which receives the broadcast), in my log files I see:

```
11-24 11:24:47.978: W/GCM/DMM(14909): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=<base.package> (has extras) }

11-24 11:24:47.978: W/GCM/DMM(14909): Receiver package not found, unregister application <base.package> sender <project.id>
```

My manifest is as follows:

```
<!-- Needed for the GCM messaging service -->
<permission
    android:name="<base.package>.client.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="<base.package>.client.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


        <!-- Needed to receive GCM broadcasts -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="<base.package>.client" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" >
    </service>
```

So it looks like what has happened, is my old application with `<base.package>` is not allowing my new application with `<base.package>.client` to register?  Is this on on the Google server side or somehow within my Eclipse project?  How can I clear it?

I have a feeling I could just create a new Google console project project and start from scratch with a new project ID, but I guess I wouldn't learn at all that way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Btw you can start from scratch but thats not necessary as if just create a new console project with .client package name and use that project id and that will do the job...

Comment: So, are you saying when you register GCM in your manifest like I did, it's permanently registered with googles service?  There's no way to clear it out?  There's nothing in my manifest keying my app to my specific project ID, so how does google know just by package?

Answer (score 0):

You included only part of the relevant manifest declarations in your question. Near the top of your manifest, you should have `<permission>` and `<uses-permission>` declarations that contain `<base.package>.permission`. You should change them to `<base.package>.client.permission`.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the issue.  I forgot to mention in my first post, but I had these changes in as well.  I just added them to my manifest above to show what I had that was NOT working.

Comment: @user1871035 Is it possible that in your server you send the optional `restricted_package_name` parameter in the notification? Also, is `<base.package>.client` the main package of your new app, as defined at the top of the manifest?

Comment: I will have to check on the restricted_package_name.  Are you saying this is on the actual call to send the GCM message within the Java code.  If so, I'm 99% sure I am not setting this field.  To answer your second question, yes, the base package defined at the top of my manifest is defined as the same, <base.package>.client.  Thank you for your help thus far, Eran.